# CKEDITOR: Form element - Selection field not opening

Tags: forms, select, ckeditor

I am trying to work with the 'forms' plugin with the CKeditor and was unable to get the select dropdown to open. I can create a selection field but when the field shows up on the editor I am unable to open it (by clicking the arrows) to select a different option on the dropdown.

Out of curiosity I tried it on the [CKeditor demo](http://ckeditor.com/demo#full) page and it was not working there either, is there a defect logged for this? Or does someone know how to get it to work?

[image: create selection field]

[image: use selection field]

Comment: Anyone for the CKEditor developer community can help me out?

Comment: I was unable to get it to work either. Closest I found was the token plugin, but I don't want a dialog.